# how to make the statement to repeat itself until it gets true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want this statement to repeat itself until the condition is true, forgot the syntax to do so

```
let gradeAmount = Number(prompt('insert a number between 1 and 5'));
const grades = [];
if (gradeAmount >= 1 && gradeAmount <= 5) {
  for (let i = 0; i < gradeAmount; i++) {
    const grade = Number(prompt('insert the grade'));

    grades.push(grade);
  }
} else {
  alert('invalid number of grades, please insert again');
  gradeAmount = Number(prompt('insert a number between 1 and 5'));
}
```

Comment: that's called a while loop - just use google if you forget syntax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `do...while`. This code will keep display `alert('invalid number of grades, please insert again')` and `window.prompt` until it meets you condition. Then it will window.prompt for user to enter the number.

```js
const grades = [];
let gradeAmount = Number(prompt('insert a number between 1 and 5'));
do{
if(gradeAmount < 1 || gradeAmount > 5){
alert('invalid number of grades, please insert again');
  gradeAmount = Number(prompt('insert a number between 1 and 5'));
  }
 }
 
 while(gradeAmount < 1 || gradeAmount > 5)
 
 
   for (let i = 0; i < gradeAmount; i++) {
    const grade = Number(prompt('insert the grade'));

    grades.push(grade);
  }
  console.log(grades)
```

Comment: I will try this out, thank you!!

Comment: @ItaiWilunski, no problem,  I will be appreciated if you find it helpful and  you accept my answer :)

Comment: for some reason every time i try to run this code now it doesnt work.

the first number the user gives gives the alarm, as well as the values that suppose to enter the loop. and after that the loop works for every number the user enters

Comment: @ItaiWilunski, what doesn't work? The window.promot or others?

Comment: it  doesnt do the test for the given number properly.

Comment: for every number i use the alert is shown and after i close the alert it works for every number, as well as numbers outside the condition limit

Comment: @ItaiWilunski, sorry, I make an mistake, I reverse the condition, but I forget to change the `&&` to `||`, Updated the code. It should work now. Check if it work!

Comment: it still doesnt work

Comment: @ItaiWilunski, curious why it doesn't work. For me, it will first let you insert a number. If the number is between 1 and 5, it will let you insert your grade and push it to an array. If not, it will keep window.prompt until user enter a number between 1 and 5

Comment: okay now it works. thank you!!

Comment: i have no idea why, but it seems not to work when the first number delivered from the user and after that it works as it should

Comment: @ItaiWilunski, not sure why it doesn't work for you, but I add an extra if statement to make sure it won't make some unexpected result for you. Check it now:)

Comment: okay now its working. thank you!!

Comment: @ItaiWilunski, no problem. Glad I could help:)